# Does lightning:recordEditForm support custom setting records?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customsetting, lightning-recordeditform

I tried to use lightning:recordEditForm to create a new custom setting record but I received an error saying

> Error in fetching record or record metadata. [Unexpected Error when
>   retrieving 'Custom_Setting__c' Layout Information ]

[image]

[I can't find any information in the official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) that custom settings are not supported for lightning:recordEditForm, is this just not documented or is there a way to get it working?

---

Update: This is the code I use

Application example code

```
<aura:application >
    <c:CSREF/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning component example code

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Custom_Setting__c">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Date_Before__c"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Date_After__c"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Site__c"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Project__c"/>
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Also, Custom_Setting__c is hierarchy custom setting with at least four fields .
Date_Before__c, Date_After__c, Site__c, Project__c
[image]

Comment: Can you post how are you trying to use/create the custom setting in your component?

Comment: yes, sure, I am going to update my question

Comment: @JayantDas Edited my question to include the code I use

Comment: Custom Settings are not supported with the component. I have provided more details as an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Even though not explicitly mentioned on the documentation, Custom Settings do not seem to be supported with `lightning:recordEditForm`. Going through the documentation, below are some details to support this.

The documentation of [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) mentions:

> `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField` support the following features.
>
> - Display a record edit layout for editing a specified record
> - Display a record create layout for creating a new record

The component depends on the [UI-API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_quick_start.htm) to fetch any layout details of the object to be able to render as create/edit screen along with combination of input fields. And because Custom Settings do not really have any layout associated with them, that is where you get to see the error when you load the component using custom setting (`Unexpected Error when retrieving 'Custom_Setting__c' Layout Information`) .

Below is an excerpt from [UI-API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_quick_start.htm) documentation:

> This resource returns all the information necessary to display a record in an app: **layout** metadata, object metadata, and record data.

For a list of objects supported by UI-API, you can find more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm).

Comment: It is a pity that 3 years have been passed but Custom Settings are still not supported by the lightning:recordEditForm

Answer (score 0):

However, this is mentioned in the documentation

[Input Field documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation) that

> See Supported Objects in lightning-record-edit-form for usage
> considerations about objects.

while [Lightning Record Form says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) that

> For a list of supported objects, see the User Interface API Developer
> Guide.

and [User Interface API Developer Guide says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm) that

> User Interface API supports all custom objects and external objects
> and many standard objects.

which means that custom settings and custom metadata are not supported.